# Is there a way I can use find_program_address used to derive a PDA as an anchor constraint

Tags: anchor, pda, constraints

Suppose I have a PDA that is supposed to be initialized by calling a CPI in my program and I want to validate that the account is valid, is there a way I could add a check to make sure that the program address passed is similar to the PDA which would be derived from the given seeds

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct 
CreateBid<'info> {
    #[account(
        mut
    )]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,

    /// CHECK: initialized by another program through the CPI
    #[account(
        mut,

    )]
    pub pda_to_initialize_through_cpi: AccountInfo<'info>,
}
```

Is there a way I could add the [`find_program_address`](https://docs.rs/solana-program/latest/solana_program/pubkey/struct.Pubkey.html#method.find_program_address) method using the `address` constraint to make sure that it is the address I expected?

```
 /// CHECK: initialized by another program through the CPI
    #[account(
        mut,
        address = find_program_address(seeds_as_slice).0
    )]
    pub pda_to_initialize_through_cpi: AccountInfo<'info>,
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `seeds` and `bump` constraints, and then also specify the program that the pda should be derived from.

For example:

```
    #[account(
        seeds = [b"some_seed"],
        bump,
        seeds::program = other_program.key()
    )]
    pub pda: AccountInfo<'info>,
    pub other_program: Program<'info, OtherProgram>
```

Here's a specific example for the metaplex metadata account:

```
    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [
            b"metadata",
            metadata_program.key().key().as_ref(),
            token_mint.key().as_ref(),
        ],
        bump,
        seeds::program = metadata_program.key()
    )]
    pub metadata_account: AccountInfo<'info>,
    pub metadata_program: Program<'info, Metadata>,
```

Comment: How can I get the bump?

Comment: When you just use the `bump` constraint, anchor will automatically derive the pda and return the bump. If the bump is stored on another account, then you can use `bump = <some_bump>` as the constraint and save some compute units on the transaction